# simplest way to dynamically display math content on web pages

Tags: math

I'd like to let people type math (latex) in a text field and show them the math content dynamically as they type on the same page. how can this be done (i'm developing on windows)?

thanx!

Answer (score 3):

For the dynamic updating part I suggest [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/). In preview mode it updates a "processed" version of what you type (just like the SO text fields).

For the math, I also advise the excellent [jsmath](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/) (checkout the [examples](http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/examples/Henrici.html)!).

A combination of the two should fit the bill.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).

It looks like the most advanced solution and the only one still under active development, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

[mimeTeX](http://www.forkosh.dreamhost.com/source_mimetex.html) or [mathTeX](http://www.forkosh.com/mathtex.html).

Comment: mathTex literally says on its web page that it is available only for linux. and for some one who isn't linux proficient mimeTex sounds somewhat complex aswell. anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Try jsMath: http://www.math.union.edu/~dpvc/jsMath/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Olivier.  I use Jay Salvat's markitup on my site. Everything is JavaScript so it's cross-platform. You can create drop-down menu's that organize icons into groups and when you click an icon, JavaScript automatically embeds the code into the textarea. Sometimes fitting the icon into a small space is challenge but it can be done.

I've used it with Drupal and am very pleased with it. js injector automatically embeds the code into specified pages and the jQuery comes for free. (There is a Windows version of Drupal as well).

John Forkosh's Mimetex then renders the equation. The query is sent via jQuery AJAX so you don't need a page refresh. I'm pretty sure there is a Windows version of Mimetex.

[Jay Salvat's Markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

[MarkItUp/MimeTex/jQuery/AJAX Implementation](http://drupal.org/project/texbar)